I am unable to add new dependencies always getting "[module name] cannot be resolved to a module"
Whenever I work on a project using Maven on VSC, I always get "[module name] cannot be resolved to a module". For example, in my project made using the JavaFX Template, only JavaFX works and when I try to load gson it does not work. It does not allow me to import or require any new dependency. This is when I add new dependencies through VSCs inbuilt add maven dependencies function.
My module-info.java
module com.example {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens com.example.controllers to javafx.fxml;

    exports com.example;
    exports com.example.controllers; 
}

My pom.xml

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>maron</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>



I tried mvn clean install but it still does not work. I also updated maven too.

Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code

I installed it but it is still the same @BasilBourque

Quote exact error message.

Hello, what is the specific error message. You can try clearing the cache and rebuilding it with the command mvn clean compile to see if that works.
